# In the code,why using fflush fixes the output?

Tags: c, input, stack, fflush

i created a stack to solve a question. Here is the insert function:

```
insert()
{
    char data;
    scanf("%c",&data);
    struct node* newNode=create_node(data);//creates a new node
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=newNode;
        tail=head;
        return;

    }
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;
    return;
```

Now,i tried pushing a few elements in stack like this,

```
main()
{
    char input[20];
    insert();
    insert();
    insert();
    insert();
    insert();
    print();
}
```

However i noticed that the *insert* after every *insert* is skipped.So it takes only **3** inputs when i should take **5**..i.e.,i gives the output after taking 3 inputs.

i was able to solve the problem by adding an **fflush** in the insert func.

*i wish to know what actually happens that causes this..*
*Also does that mean we cannot take input like the way i did ?*

Comment: Did you do `fflush(stdin)`?

Comment: yes,iam guessing it flushes(or removes) the newline character which was otherwise going as input for the next scanf().

Comment: OK. `fflush(stdin)` works on Linux and windows but is *undefined* in standard C. In general, you should avoid using `scanf()` family functions for handling user inputs as they are not very useful at handling errors/invlid inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
scanf("%c", &data);
```

with

```
scanf(" %c", &data);
```

to fix the issue. The space character behind `%c` skips all whitespace characters including none, until the first non-whitespace character as specified in the C11 standard:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails

The reason why your program takes just 3 inputs instead of 5 is because there was a newline character(`\n`) prevailing in the standard input stream(`stdin`). Remembering pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering data for the `scanf`? This character(newline character or `\n`) is **not** captured by this `scanf`. This character is instead captured by the `scanf` with `%c` when it is called the next time. This is why this `scanf` doesn't wait for further input and "skips" some inputs.

The function `fflush`, when used with `stdin`, *might* work in *some* implementations although the behavior is said to be Undefined by the standard:

> **7.21.5.2 The fflush function**
>
> [...]
>
> 2. If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.